# Database injection into a validation attribute with ASP MVC and Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I need some help - I am trying to use a custom validation attribute in an ASP.NET MVC web project that needs to make a database call.

I have windsor successfully working for the controllers and the IRepository interface is injected normally. The problem arrises when I need to inject the repository into the attribute class.

The attribute class has the following code:

```
public class ValidateUniqueUrlNodeAttribute : AbstractValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string message;
    private readonly IArticleRepository articleRepository;

    public ValidateUniqueUrlNodeAttribute(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public ValidateUniqueUrlNodeAttribute(string message, IArticleRepository articleRepository):this(message)
    {
        this.articleRepository = articleRepository;
    }
    public override IValidator Build()
    {
        var validator = new UniqueUrlNodeValidator(articleRepository) { ErrorMessage = message };

        ConfigureValidatorMessage(validator);

        return validator;
    }
```

My problem is that I cannot seem to make Windsor intercept the contruction of the attribute to pass in the IArticleRepository

The current code in my global.asax file is as follows:

```
container = new WindsorContainer();
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new WindsorControllerFactory(Container));
   container
     .RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
     .AddComponent<IArticleRepository, ArticleRepository>()
     .AddComponent<ValidateUniqueUrlNodeAttribute>();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK no dependency injection container can directly manage an attribute, since it's instantiated by the runtime and there's no way to intercept that.

However, they can *cheat* by either:

1. Using a static gateway to the container ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553330/how-do-i-use-windsor-to-inject-dependencies-into-actionfilterattributes/553405#553405)), or
2. Using a "BuildUp" feature that injects whatever dependencies are found within an already-constructed object. This is called [BuildUp in Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440949.aspx) or [InjectProperties in Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ComponentCreation#Property_Injection).

Windsor doesn't support #2 ([ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447193), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851940)), so you can either:

1. Try one of the hacks to make Windsor support #2 ([hack1](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2008/11/08/dependency-injection-with-aspnet-mvc-action-filters/), [hack2](http://groups.google.com/group/castle-project-users/browse_thread/thread/98f27000d07683e4))
2. Use a [static gateway](https://rhino-tools.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/rhino-tools/trunk/commons/Rhino.Commons/RhinoContainer/IoC.cs)
3. Implement your own [IValidatorBuilder](https://svn.castleproject.org/svn/castle/trunk/Components/Validator/Castle.Components.Validator/IValidatorBuilder.cs) and make it use Windsor to create validators. I'm sure this is implemented somewhere but I can't find it right now...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps, but I subclassed `ValidationAttribute` to expose a `Resolve<T>()` method like so:

```
public abstract class IocValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return IocHelper.Container().Resolve<T>();
    }
}
```

Then it can be used in any custom ValidatorAttribute that needs to hit a database:

```
public class UniqueEmailAttribute : IocValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        ICustomerRepository customerRepository = Resolve<ICustomerRepository>();

        return customerRepository.FindByEmail(value.ToString()) == null;
    }
}
```

I think it's a variation of the 'Static Gateway' approach mentioned by Mauricio Scheffer. I don't know if this is a good design or not. I'm not a huge fan of it, I'd rather the dependency was injected more 'elegantly', though I can't use constructor injection obviously, I'd like to use Property injection but can't work out a way to hook into the ASP.NET MVC framework code to do this (I've even pored though the MVC2 source code).

Comment: Where do you get IocHelper from?

Comment: @soniiic looks like an evil static

Answer (score 0):

I was able to wire it up [using Autofac as it happens, but it's just constructor injection via the ASP.NET MVC `DependencyResolver`] [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35214460/11635), enabling one to write:

```
class MyModel 
{
    ...
    [Required, StringLength(42)]
    [ValidatorService(typeof(MyDiDependentValidator), ErrorMessage = "It's simply unacceptable")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class MyDiDependentValidator : Validator<MyModel>
{
    readonly IUnitOfWork _iLoveWrappingStuff;

    public MyDiDependentValidator(IUnitOfWork iLoveWrappingStuff)
    {
        _iLoveWrappingStuff = iLoveWrappingStuff;
    }

    protected override bool IsValid(MyModel instance, object value)
    {
        var attempted = (string)value;
        return _iLoveWrappingStuff.SaysCanHazCheez(instance, attempted);
    }
}
```

With some helper classes (look over there), you wire it up e.g. in ASP.NET MVC like so in the `Global.asax` :-

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapterFactory(
    typeof(ValidatorServiceAttribute),
    (metadata, context, attribute) =>
        new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorEx(metadata, context, attribute, true));
```

Answer (score -1):

Hmm.

Can you test the effect of removing the (string message) ctor, and see if that at least forces Castle to use the ctor with the Repostiory ?

Otherwise we call AddComponent(name, type, type). Other than that it really should work...

Also does this hint at my first idea ? [How do I use Windsor to inject dependencies into ActionFilterAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553330/how-do-i-use-windsor-to-inject-dependencies-into-actionfilterattributes)

Comment: Sorry, I can't remove the string CTOR as the attribute looks like this:
[ValidateUniqueUrlNode("Please enter a unique Url")]
        public string UrlNode { get; set; }

Should this be different?

Comment: Dahhh. Still scratching head... I'll have a search