# Asp.Net MVC3: Set custom IServiceProvider in ValidationContext so validators can resolve services

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control

***Update 18th December 2012***

*Since this question seems to be getting quite a few views, I should point out that the accepted answer is not the solution I used, but it does provide the links and resources to build a solution, but, to my mind, not the ideal solution.  My answer contains* ***replacements*** *for standard parts of the MVC framework; and you should only use those if you are comfortable checking that they still work for future versions (some private code was ripped out of the official sources, because there wasn't enough extensibility in the base classes).*

*I can confirm, however, that these two classes also work for Asp.Net MVC 4 as well as 3.*

*It is also possible to repeat a similar implementation for the Asp.Net Web API framework as well, which I have done recently.*

***End update***

I have a type that has a lot of 'standard' validation (required etc) but also a bit of custom validation as well.

Some of this validation requires grabbing hold of a service object and looking up some lower-level (i.e. 'beneath' the Model layer) meta data using one of the other properties as a key.  The meta data then controls whether one or more properties are required as well as valid formats for those properties.

To be more concrete - the type is a Card Payment object, simplified to two of the properties in question as follows:

```
public class CardDetails
{
  public string CardTypeID { get; set; }
  public string CardNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a service:

```
public interface ICardTypeService
{
  ICardType GetCardType(string cardTypeID);
}
```

`ICardType` then contains different bits of information - the two here that are crucial being:

```
public interface ICardType
{
  //different cards support one or more card lengths
  IEnumerable<int> CardNumberLengths { get; set; }
  //e.g. - implementation of the Luhn algorithm
  Func<string, bool> CardNumberVerifier { get; set; }
}
```

My controllers all have the ability to resolve an `ICardTypeService` using a standard pattern i.e.

```
 var service = Resolve<ICardTypeService>();
```

(Although I should mention that the framework behind this call is proprietary)

Which they gain via the use of a common interface

```
public interface IDependant
{
  IDependencyResolver Resolver { get; set; }
}
```

My framework then takes care of assigning the most-specific dependency resolver available for the controller instance when it is constructed (either by another resolver, or by the MVC standard controller factory).  That `Resolve` method in the last-but one code block is a simple wrapper around this `Resolver` member.

So - if I can grab the selected `ICardType` for the payment that is received from the browser, I can then perform initial checks on card number length etc.  The issue is, how to resolve the service from within my override of `IsValid(object, ValidationContext)` override of `ValidationAttribute`?

I need to pass through the current controller's dependency resolver to the validation context.  I see that `ValidationContext` both implements `IServiceProvider` and has an instance of `IServiceContainer` - so clearly I should be able to create a wrapper for my service resolver that also implements one of those (probably `IServiceProvider`).

I've already noted that in all places where a `ValidationContext` is produced by the MVC framework, the service provider is *always* passed null.

So at what point in the MVC pipeline should I be looking to override the core behaviour and inject my service provider?

I should add that this will *not* be the only scenario in which I need to do something like this - so ideally I'd like something which I can apply to the pipeline so that all `ValidationContext`s are configured with the current service provider for the current controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about creating a model validator, using a modelValidatorProvider, instead of using validation attributes? This way you're not dependant on ValidationAttribute but can create your own validation implementation (this will work in addition the existing DataAnnotations validation).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelvalidatorprovider.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Experience-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Beta-the-New-Dependency-Injection-Support-Part2.aspx#s10-new-support-for-validator-provider

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Customizing-ASP-NET-MVC-2-Metadata-and-Validation.aspx#s2-validation

Comment: some good articles there, thanks; and I could certainly get close this way - however there is a bit more to override here than I really like for a catch-all solution. Equally I like the attribute-based validation as it's very visible (especially to other devs in my team who, as yet, aren't as comfortable with MVC yet - not that I said that in particular was a requirement).

Could certainly do it this way tho, so +1.

Comment: You can still implement attribute based validation using a custom model validator provider. DataAnnotations are implemented the same way. You just don't have to use the same approach as DataAnnotations.

Comment: I have found quite a low impact way (which I'm going to post up when I've verified that it works!) to make it work for all attribute-based validators that don't use their own adapters. I was already working on it before you posted your answer - just didn't want to jump the gun :); what remains to see if it meets with community approval!

Comment: marking this as answer since my solution requires dilligence when upgrading to future versions of MVC which should only be adopted by developers comfortable with re-plumbing the lower level bits of MVC.

Answer (score 5):

On MVC 5.2, you can <strike>leverage</strike>steal [@Andras's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5222249/11635) and the MVC source and:

## 1. Derive a `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorEx` from `DataAnnotationsModelValidator`

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    // From https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DataAnnotationsModelValidator.cs
    // commit 5fa60ca38b58, Apr 02, 2015
    // Only diff is adding of secton guarded by THERE_IS_A_BETTER_EXTENSION_POINT
    public class DataAnnotationsModelValidatorEx : DataAnnotationsModelValidator
    {
        readonly bool _shouldHotwireValidationContextServiceProviderToDependencyResolver;

        public DataAnnotationsModelValidatorEx(
            ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, ValidationAttribute attribute,
            bool shouldHotwireValidationContextServiceProviderToDependencyResolver=false)
            : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {
           _shouldHotwireValidationContextServiceProviderToDependencyResolver =
                shouldHotwireValidationContextServiceProviderToDependencyResolver;
        }
    }
}
```

## 2. Clone the base impl of `public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)`

## 3. <strike>Apply the hack</strike> Render the elegant incision after `Validate` creates the context:-

> `public override IEnumerable Validate(object container)
>   {
>       // Per the WCF RIA Services team, instance can never be null (if you have
>       // no parent, you pass yourself for the "instance" parameter).
>       string memberName = Metadata.PropertyName ?? Metadata.ModelType.Name;
>       ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(container ?? Metadata.Model)
>       {
>           DisplayName = Metadata.GetDisplayName(),
>           MemberName = memberName
>       };`

```
#if !THERE_IS_A_BETTER_EXTENSION_POINT
   if(_shouldHotwireValidationContextServiceProviderToDependencyResolver 
       && Attribute.RequiresValidationContext)
       context.InitializeServiceProvider(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService);
#endif
```

> ```
>    ValidationResult result = Attribute.GetValidationResult(Metadata.Model, context);
>     if (result != ValidationResult.Success)
>     {
>         // ModelValidationResult.MemberName is used by invoking validators (such as ModelValidator) to
>         // construct the ModelKey for ModelStateDictionary. When validating at type level we want to append the
>         // returned MemberNames if specified (e.g. person.Address.FirstName). For property validation, the
>         // ModelKey can be constructed using the ModelMetadata and we should ignore MemberName (we don't want
>         // (person.Name.Name). However the invoking validator does not have a way to distinguish between these two
>         // cases. Consequently we'll only set MemberName if this validation returns a MemberName that is different
>         // from the property being validated.
>
>        string errorMemberName = result.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault();
>         if (String.Equals(errorMemberName, memberName, StringComparison.Ordinal))
>         {
>             errorMemberName = null;
>         }
>
>        var validationResult = new ModelValidationResult
>         {
>             Message = result.ErrorMessage,
>             MemberName = errorMemberName
>         };
>
>        return new ModelValidationResult[] { validationResult };
>     }
>
>    return Enumerable.Empty<ModelValidationResult>();
> }
> ```

## 4. Tell MVC about the new `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` in town

after your Global.asax does `DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container))` :-

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapterFactory(
    typeof(ValidatorServiceAttribute),
    (metadata, context, attribute) => new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorEx(metadata, context, attribute, true));
```

## 5. Use your imagination to <strike>abuse your new Service Locator</strike> consume using ctor injection via `GetService` in your `ValidationAttribute`, for example:

```
public class ValidatorServiceAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    readonly Type _serviceType;

    public ValidatorServiceAttribute(Type serviceType)
    {
        _serviceType = serviceType;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, 
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validator = CreateValidatorService(validationContext);
        var instance = validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        var resultOrValidationResultEmpty = validator.Validate(instance, value);
        if (resultOrValidationResultEmpty == ValidationResult.Success)
            return resultOrValidationResultEmpty;
        if (resultOrValidationResultEmpty.ErrorMessage == string.Empty)
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        return resultOrValidationResultEmpty;
    }

    IModelValidator CreateValidatorService(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return (IModelValidator)validationContext.GetService(_serviceType);
    }
}
```

Allows you to slap it on your model:-

```
class MyModel 
{
    ...
    [Required, StringLength(42)]
    [ValidatorService(typeof(MyDiDependentValidator), 
        ErrorMessage = "It's simply unacceptable")]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

which wires it to a:

```
public class MyDiDependentValidator : Validator<MyModel>
{
    readonly IUnitOfWork _iLoveWrappingStuff;

    public MyDiDependentValidator(IUnitOfWork iLoveWrappingStuff)
    {
        _iLoveWrappingStuff = iLoveWrappingStuff;
    }

    protected override bool IsValid(MyModel instance, object value)
    {
        var attempted = (string)value;
        return _iLoveWrappingStuff.SaysCanHazCheez(instance, attempted);
    }
}
```

The preceding two are connected by:

```
interface IModelValidator
{
    ValidationResult Validate(object instance, object value);
}

public abstract class Validator<T> : IModelValidator
{
    protected virtual bool IsValid(T instance, object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(
            "TODO: implement bool IsValid(T instance, object value)" +
            " or ValidationResult Validate(T instance, object value)");
    }

    protected virtual ValidationResult Validate(T instance, object value)
    {
        return IsValid(instance, value) 
            ? ValidationResult.Success 
            : new ValidationResult("");
    }

    ValidationResult IModelValidator.Validate(object instance, object value)
    {
        return Validate((T)instance, value);
    }
}
```

**I'm open to corrections, but most of all, ASP.NET team, would you be open to a PR to add a constructor with this facility to `DataAnnotationsModelValidator`?**

Comment: Nice walkthrough!

Answer (score 4):

## Update

In addition to the class shown below, I've done a similar thing for `IValidatableObject` implementations as well <strike>(short notes towards the end of the answer instead of a full code sample because then the answer just gets too long)</strike> - I've added the code for that class as well in response to a comment - it does make the answer *very* long, but at least you'll have all the code you need.

## Original

Since I'm targeting `ValidationAttribute`-based validation at the moment I researched where MVC creates the `ValidationContext` that gets fed to the `GetValidationResult` method of that class.

Turns out it's in the `DataAnnotationsModelValidator`'s `Validate` method:

```
public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container) {
  // Per the WCF RIA Services team, instance can never be null (if you have
  // no parent, you pass yourself for the "instance" parameter).
  ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(
    container ?? Metadata.Model, null, null);
  context.DisplayName = Metadata.GetDisplayName();

  ValidationResult result = 
    Attribute.GetValidationResult(Metadata.Model, context);

  if (result != ValidationResult.Success) {
    yield return new ModelValidationResult {
      Message = result.ErrorMessage
    };
  }
}
```

(Copied and reformatted from MVC3 RTM Source)

So I figured some extensibility here would be in order:

```
public class DataAnnotationsModelValidatorEx : DataAnnotationsModelValidator
{
  public DataAnnotationsModelValidatorEx(
    ModelMetadata metadata, 
    ControllerContext context, 
    ValidationAttribute attribute)
    : base(metadata, context, attribute)
  {
  }

  public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
  {
    ValidationContext context = CreateValidationContext(container);

    ValidationResult result = 
      Attribute.GetValidationResult(Metadata.Model, context);

    if (result != ValidationResult.Success)
    {
      yield return new ModelValidationResult
      {
        Message = result.ErrorMessage
      };
    }
  }

  // begin Extensibility

  protected virtual ValidationContext CreateValidationContext(object container)
  {
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = CreateServiceProvider(container);
    //TODO: add virtual method perhaps for the third parameter?
    ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(
      container ?? Metadata.Model, 
      serviceProvider, 
      null);
    context.DisplayName = Metadata.GetDisplayName();
    return context;
  }

  protected virtual IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(object container)
  {
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;

    IDependant dependantController = 
      ControllerContext.Controller as IDependant;

    if (dependantController != null && dependantController.Resolver != null)
      serviceProvider = new ResolverServiceProviderWrapper
                        (dependantController.Resolver);
    else
      serviceProvider = ControllerContext.Controller as IServiceProvider;
    return serviceProvider;
  }
}
```

So I check first for my `IDependant` interface from the controller, in which case I create an instance of a wrapper class that acts as an adapter between my `IDependencyResolver` interface and `System.IServiceProvider`.

I thought I'd also handle cases where a controller itself is an `IServiceProvider` too (not that that applies in my case - but it's a more general solution).

Then I make the `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider` use this validator by default, instead of the original:

```
//register the new factory over the top of the standard one.
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterDefaultAdapterFactory(
  (metadata, context, attribute) => 
    new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorEx(metadata, context, attribute));
```

Now 'normal' `ValidationAttribute`-based validators, can resolve services:

```
public class ExampleAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  protected override ValidationResult 
    IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
    ICardTypeService service = 
      (ICardTypeService)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ICardTypeService));
  }
}
```

This still leaves direct `ModelValidator`-derived needing to be reimplemented to support the same technique - although they already have access to the `ControllerContext`, so it's less of an issue.

## Update

A similar thing has to be done if you want `IValidatableObject`-implementing types to be able to resolve services during the implementation of `Validate` without having to keep deriving your own adapters for each type.

- Derive a new class from `ValidatableObjectAdapter`, I called it `ValidatableObjectAdapterEx`
- from MVCs v3 RTM source, copy the `Validate` and `ConvertResults` private method of that class.
- Adjust the first method to remove references to internal MVC resources, and
- change how the `ValidationContext` is constructed

## Update (in response to comment below)

Here's the code for the `ValidatableObjectAdapterEx` - and I'll point out hopefully more clearly that `IDependant` and `ResolverServiceProviderWrapper` used here and before are types that only apply to my environment - if you're using a global, statically-accessible DI container, however, then it should be trivial to re-implement these two classes' `CreateServiceProvider` methods appropriately.

```
public class ValidatableObjectAdapterEx : ValidatableObjectAdapter
{
  public ValidatableObjectAdapterEx(ModelMetadata metadata, 
                                    ControllerContext context)
   : base(metadata, context) { }

  public override IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> Validate(object container)
  {
    object model = base.Metadata.Model;
    if (model != null)
    {
      IValidatableObject instance = model as IValidatableObject;
      if (instance == null)
      {
        //the base implementation will throw an exception after 
        //doing the same check - so let's retain that behaviour
        return base.Validate(container);
      }
      /* replacement for the core functionality */
      ValidationContext validationContext = CreateValidationContext(instance);
      return this.ConvertResults(instance.Validate(validationContext));
    }
    else
      return base.Validate(container);  /*base returns an empty set 
                                          of values for null. */
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Called by the Validate method to create the ValidationContext
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="instance"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  protected virtual ValidationContext CreateValidationContext(object instance)
  {
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = CreateServiceProvider(instance);
    //TODO: add virtual method perhaps for the third parameter?
    ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(
      instance ?? Metadata.Model,
      serviceProvider,
      null);
    return context;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Called by the CreateValidationContext method to create an IServiceProvider
  /// instance to be passed to the ValidationContext.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="container"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  protected virtual IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(object container)
  {
    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;

    IDependant dependantController = ControllerContext.Controller as IDependant;

    if (dependantController != null && dependantController.Resolver != null)
    {
      serviceProvider = 
        new ResolverServiceProviderWrapper(dependantController.Resolver);
    }
    else
      serviceProvider = ControllerContext.Controller as IServiceProvider;

    return serviceProvider;
  }

  //ripped from v3 RTM source
  private IEnumerable<ModelValidationResult> ConvertResults(
    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> results)
  {
    foreach (ValidationResult result in results)
    {
      if (result != ValidationResult.Success)
      {
        if (result.MemberNames == null || !result.MemberNames.Any())
        {
          yield return new ModelValidationResult { Message = result.ErrorMessage };
        }
        else
        {
          foreach (string memberName in result.MemberNames)
          {
            yield return new ModelValidationResult 
             { Message = result.ErrorMessage, MemberName = memberName };
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## End Code

With that class in place, you can register this as the default adapter for `IValidatableObject` instances with the line:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.
  RegisterDefaultValidatableObjectAdapterFactory(
    (metadata, context) => new ValidatableObjectAdapterEx(metadata, context)
  );
```

Comment: As long as you don't have to change the ModelValidator for every concrete type, I think this works.

Comment: Yep, already started rolling it out on a few types now, working fine! Then there is the solutions you've pointed to for other validation. All bases covered, just the way I like it :)

Comment: I'll just add this though -> If you need to copy and paste private methods from the parent class it *might* mean that you're doing something that you're not supposed to do.

Comment: lol - I am aware of that; although it *might* equally mean that there's a missing extensibility point in the framework...

In this case there is no other way of taking advantage of service providers during MVC validation unless you create and register a special validator for every type whose validator will need them.  Each one of those is also likely to contain the same code or base class - so why not make it the default behaviour.

Comment: Just made an identical implementation. I wish Microsoft would choose to make this work out of the box for MVC4 and the DependencyResolver. IServiceProvider shares the same signature, so the only thing needed to be changed is to make IDependencyResolver implement IServiceProvider, and pass it in when creating the ValidationContext.

Comment: Yeah I know! I suppose we can be thankful that, unlike asp.net, we can make it work. but you're right, its something that needs to be in there.  it does seem odd that this is all plumbed in, but without the bootstrapping to make it work!

Comment: Any chance you could post your code for ValidatableObjectAdapterEx?

Comment: yeah. sure,  I'll try and remember to do this when I get to work later

Comment: @Kelly answer updated with my implementation of `ValidatableObjectAdapterEx`