# How do I create a unique field in MVC Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This is my model class in C# MVC project. I want to set Membership Id as a Unique field ?

```
public class Customer
{
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string MembershipID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this object mapped to some ORM, like EF?

Comment: yes, indeed you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16678625/asp-net-mvc-4-ef5-unique-property-in-model-best-practice

Comment: This is EF MVC project

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework  does not support UNIQUE for the attributes so we have to create a function for that.
I advise you to use[FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/start), it's easy to take in hand

```
public class Customer
{
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string MembershipID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

You would define a set of validation rules for this class by inheriting from

```
    using FluentValidation;

    public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {

    public CustomerValidator() {
        RuleFor(customer => customer.EmailAddress).NotNull().Must(UniqueAddmail);
      }

   public bool UniqueAddmail (string EmailAddress)
        {
            return new AnnuaireDbEntities().Wilaya.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Nom == EmailAddress) == null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess, since you did not mention what the key is in your class.

Entity Framework does not support `unique` columns as per DataAnnotations. The only thing you can do is set one column as the primary key in combination with the other ID column being a Guid.

Assuming `CustomerID` is your primary key:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public Guid MembershipID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

assuming your MembershipID is your primary key:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Customer
{

    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int MembershipID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

By making one of the columns a guid your chances of generating 2 keys of the same value are near zero.

Comment: Could you please show me How I can add unique column in Context class?? Because I need to set membership Id as unique some how.

Comment: Which `context` class? The DbContext?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string MembershipId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Company
 {
     public string MembershipId { get; set; }
     public string Name {get; set;}

 }
public class CustomersBankAccount
 {
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int CustomerId { get; set; }
 }
```

The convention when you want to build a database with code first convention is to have a "Id" (foreign key) part integrated in your properties.
   Of course I recommend that all properties are declared virtual so that EF can grasp into your code and enable some features. like an efficient tracking mechnaism

So : If you have a property on the object named ID, EF assumes the property
holds the primary key value and sets up an auto-incrementing (identity) key column in SQL Server
to hold the property value.

Edit:

"On the object" meaning object of Customer. Essentially the primary key in your example is in customer , and the foreign key is in all other tables that are related to customer. A primary key cannot be duplicated or null. A foreign key - yes.  It is possible that the same customer can have multiple bank accounts.  :)
  So if you are wondering , where is the plumbing to set your keys , stop. MVC can just look in the code above and decide (on a scaffolding selection) how to make the tabels in your DB. You don't have to indicate nothing in your code apart from what you allready seen (the "Id" an the end )

Edit based on my comment:

```
  public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [Remote("CheckMembershipIdActionMethod", "CorrespondingController")]
    public string MembershipId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you recommend properties being virtual, why don't you give an example by making the `MembershipId` in the `Customer` class virtual?

Comment: @Serv Virtual properties are not
required, but they do give EF control on building it's own mechanisms

Comment: CustomerId is the primary key. And membership ID is the unique field like a National Identity card number

Comment: @user2901979 Ok . You can use in this case the Remote Attribute. It's job is to assure that your function is fuffiled. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx