# ASP.NET MVC validation doesn't clear when other value changes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

On a certain screen of our application, we have two dates which both have a remote validation attribute on them in the viewmodel. The attribute will compare the dates and see if they are filled in.

The validation logic is working correctly, but clearing the validation messages is giving us some issues.

Example:

```
Date 1 -> 05/05/2015

Date 2 -> 06/06/2015
```

Date 2 gets emptied
=> `Validation on date 2 triggers and a message appears above the textbox of date 2`

We change the value of date 1
=> `Validation on date 1 triggers because date 2 is empty`

We fill in date 2
=> `Validation message of date 2 disappears but validation message of date 1 stays`

Is there a way to make the validation on date 1 disappear as well, when the value of date 2 gets filled in correctly?

Comment: Do these two have the same `name` attribute in html?

Comment: Can we see the form and the validation?

Comment: maybe you can post your code, as in  your view controls ?

Comment: Why do you think you need Remote validation for this task? You seem to be wanting to compare 2 values which exist in the form, in which case Remote validation is not the correct approach. What rules are you actually applying?

Comment: You will need a custom validation attribute, this has been well explained and documented here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906228/how-to-validate-one-field-related-to-anothers-value-in-asp-net-mvc-3