# c# mvc how to validate 3rd column Value Based on Two column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-validation

Here I have three properties Like

```
Public Class Addition{
public Int Val1{get;se;}
public Int Val2{get;se;}
public Int Val3{get;se;}
}
```

In .cshtml **Val1=10;Val2=20;** If User Entre **Val3=30** Then How can i validate **Val3** Value Should Be **LessThan or Equal to 30** Beacause (10+20=30)

Comment: use a custom validation attribute. I recommend you fluent validation .NET. refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906228/how-to-validate-one-field-related-to-anothers-value-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Could you please give hint how can i bind three values at a time

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem are you facing to solve it. 
it shouldn't be complex
You can use

```
if(Val3 > (Val1 + Val2))                                                             
{             
  //Show Your Message
  return;
}
```

Upvote if helps